# python: print values from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

```
generic_drugs_mapping={'MORPHINE':[86],
                       'OXYCODONE':[87],
                       'OXYMORPHONE':[99],
                       'METHADONE':[82],
                       'BUPRENORPHINE':[28],
                       'HYDROMORPHONE':[54],
                       'CODEINE':[37],
                       'HYDROCODONE':[55]}
```

How do I return `86`?

This does not seem to work:

```
print generic_drugs_mapping['MORPHINE'[0]]
```

Comment: Any particular reason why each value is a list of one number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list is the value stored under the key. The part that gets the value out is `generic_drugs_mapping['MORPHINE']` so this has the value `[86]`. Try moving the index outside like this :

```
generic_drugs_mapping['MORPHINE'][0]
```

Answer (score 6):

You have a bracket in the wrong place:

```
print generic_drugs_mapping['MORPHINE'][0]
```

Your code is indexing the string `'MORPHINE'`, so it's equivalent to

```
print generic_drugs_mapping['M']
```

Since `'M'` is not a key in your dictionary, you won't get the results you expect.

Comment: Not sure what you meant with the second part but it is wrong 'M' is not a key in the dict that he setup.

Comment: and if `'M'` was a key in his dictionary, he still wouldn't get the expected results, unless 'M' mapped to `86` ;-)